# How to find out pairs of opening and closing html tags using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to find out pairs of opening and closing html tags in javascript?

So I've an array of parsed html:

```
/// this is just markup only : any inner text is omitted for simplicity.


const parsedHtml = [
    '<div class="container">',
    '<div class="wrapper">',
    '<h3>',
    '</h3>',
    '<p>',
    '</p>',
   '<span>',
    '<a href="#">',
     '<img src="./img.svg">',
    '</span>',
    '</div>',
    '</div>'
]

// this whole array is a block of html code (nesting is in the above order)
```

So the idea here is to find opening and closing tag pairs;

(just the index.)

So that I can separate out blocks of code ... like this:

```
<div class="container">
...
</div>


// or

<h3>
</h3>

//or 

<span>
...
</span>
```

Just need a way to find the index of closing tag that matches an opening tag.
(think it as of opening blocks of code in vscode)

I could have done a check whether `parsedHtml[i].startsWith('</')`... but still this does not guarantee an opening and a closing pair like this:

```
<div> ---> opening

</div> --->  closing

[pair]
```

**NOTE**

This is for finding nesting of tags so that I can indent the html  likewise && show each of them as blocks. I don't wanna use packages like parse5, marked, prismjs, or highlight js.

My requirement is custom. -> (Just to find the opening and closing tag pairs, so that I can find how things are nested from the above parsed html array)

Comment: use ide like visual code

Comment: No. This is for an html webpage... not to be done on vs code.. (we have extensions for that purpose ... right)... this is for parsing and displaying html in a specific manner inside a webpage..

Answer (score 0):

That's my approach:

```
var parsedHtml = [
   '<div class="container">',
   '<div class="wrapper">',
   '<h3>',
   '</h3>',
   '<p>',
   '</p>',
   '<span>',
   '<a href="#">',
   '<img src="./img.svg">',
   '</span>',
   '</div>',
   '</div>'
];
var getTag = (s) => s.replace(/<|>/gi, '').split(' ')[0];
var isCloseTag = (t) => t.includes('/');

var indices = parsedHtml.map(getTag).reduce(collectIndices, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(indices)); // {"div":[[0,11],[1,10]],"h3":[[2,3]],"p":[[4,5]],"span":[[6,9]],"a":[[7]],"img":[[8]]}

function collectIndices(indices, tag, i) {
   const tagName = tag.replace('/', '');
   if (!(tagName in indices)) {
      indices[tagName] = [[i]];
      return indices;
   }
   if (isCloseTag(tag)) {
      indices[tagName].reverse().find((ins) => ins.length === 1).push(i);
      return indices;
   }
   indices[tagName].push([i]);
   return indices;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer here using js regex: https://www.octoparse.com/blog/using-regular-expression-to-match-html

All you have to do is put the tag in that you are looking for.

If I were looking for the a tag:
`/<a\s*.*>\s*.*<\/a>/gi`

You can test it out with this regex tool: https://regexr.com/